# Functions are not working in Ajax after a while

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have input which on change should send it is value to ajax and get response back. Ajax is working correct and enters to success,but does not working `click` function inside it if i do not do changes or click. If i click immediately after response it works, but if i do not do changes in 4-5 seconds it something like close the session. How can i avoid this timing?

here is my example of ajax

```js
$('#unvan_search').on('keyup change', function() {

  var unvan = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {
      'tpIdRegion': region_type_id_j + '_' + region_id_j,
      'road': unvan,
      'guid': my_key
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
      console.log('before send');
    },
    success: function(e) {
      console.log('suceess');
      var output = [];


      for (var i = 0; i < e.names.length; i++) {
        output.push('<li class="get_street es-visible" idx="' + e.names[i].X + '" idy="' + e.names[i].Y + '" id="' + e.names[i].ID + '" value="' + e.names[i].ID + '" style="display: block;">' + e.names[i].Name + '</li>');
        console.log('filled');
      };
      $('#unvan_select_div ul').html(output.join(''));

      $("#unvan_select_div ul").on("click", '.get_street', function() {
        //MY CODE HERE WHICH I CAN NOT USE AFTER 4-5 SECONDS
      });

    },
    error: function(x, t, m) {
      alert("error");
    }
  });


});
```

Comment: you could move the get_street click function out of your ajax success

Comment: Looks like you are duplicate binding on the `#unvan_select_div ul` element(s)

Answer (score 0):

This binding here:

```
$("#unvan_select_div ul").on("click", '.get_street', function() { ... }
```

There’s no need to declare it in the `success` callback. This kind of delegate bindings is there for that purpose: being able to handle events on elements created at a later stage

Answer (score 0):

It may work if you structure it like this.

```
var ret = false;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {
      'tpIdRegion': region_type_id_j + '_' + region_id_j,
      'road': unvan,
      'guid': my_key
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
      console.log('before send');
    },
    success: function(e) {
      ret = true;
      console.log('suceess');
      var output = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < e.names.length; i++) {
        output.push('<li class="get_street es-visible" idx="' + e.names[i].X + '" idy="' + e.names[i].Y + '" id="' + e.names[i].ID + '" value="' + e.names[i].ID + '" style="display: block;">' + e.names[i].Name + '</li>');
        console.log('filled');
      };

      return;
    },
    error: function(x, t, m) {
      alert("error");
    }
  });
});
if(ret) {
      $('#unvan_select_div ul').html(output.join(''));

      $("#unvan_select_div ul").on("click", '.get_street', function() {
        //MY CODE HERE WHICH I CAN NOT USE AFTER 4-5 SECONDS
      });
}
```